# The sysvol permissions for one or more GPOs on this domain controller are not in sync with the permissions for the GPOs on the baseline domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, file-replication-services

I have recently installed a second domain controller and all replication seems to be working fine except for group policy - In windows 2012r2, through the new Group Policy Management, when I click on "Detect Now", results show ACLs not in sync with the baseline domain...

Environment:

DC1: Windows 2008 R2;
DC2: Windows 2012 R2;
Forest & Domain Functional levels: Windows 2003;
Replication Type: FRS;

I have run dcdiag, looked at event logs, repadmin /showrepl etc and everything seems fine but group policies won't sync… I've checked the sysvol ACL's in both DC's and they seem to have the same permissions… Also the group policy central store has replicated correctly (which is sysvol)…

I found someone else has this problem here http://sysadminconcombre.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/microsoft-dfs-r-problem-sysvol.html and a resolution which involved restarting DFSR … but I have FRS since the DFL is 2003 :(

**My question is, is there any way to fix this without migrating to DFSR or should I move to DFSR first? … Everything says that I shouldn't move from FRS to DFSR without replication working 'perfectly' ….**

Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: Why is your FL at 2003?  That's the first thing I'd do something about.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I managed to fix this by manually applying the sysvol ACL's for the policies at both servers... for some reason I had to add the domain\administrators group as full control for each policy under sysvol\policies and then it synced fine.... everythings working now and I'll look at migrating to DFRS later when we can upgrade the DFL, Cheers

Anyone else seeing this problem - if you only have one or two policies it might be quicker to back up the settings, delete them all out and then add them back in again which would have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs when a GPO has changed on the local computer but a replication event has not completed to the other participating Domain Controllers. You can force replication to the other DCs in the Forest "Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | %{repadmin /syncall /edjQSA $_.hostname}" or simply wait for 15-20 minutes and refresh the GPMC. This is by design and will typically resolve itself on the next replication cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when using Detect Now.  Any time I changed the security filtering on a GPO, the ACLs for sysvol would show as having a problem.  On one DC, the policy in sysvol had the permission change, but on the other it did not.  For over an hour this was the case.  Then when I came to work the next day, everything was fine. In my case, it seems, that it is taking a long time to replicate the permissions, but a new GPO replicates instantly when it is created.

In my test domain with only a handful of GPOs (my real domain has manay), I get the same error when I Detect Now; however, when I close and reopen GPMC, everything is fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Old questions but still ranks high so I thought I might chime in. I just had this problem with one of our DCs, it showed errors like "The version numbers for one or more GPOs on this domain controller are not in sync with the versions for the GPOs on the Baseline domain controller" or even "Active Directory or SysVol is inaccessible on this domain controller or an object is missing".

In the end, a simple reboot of the offending DC solved the problem. If I click "Detect Now", everything is in sync now. Just something you can try before digging deep in the logs.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem with our environment and simply found that the ACL's were showing bad on only VERY OLD GPO's (over 10 yrs).  I simply removed them, as they were not in use any longer and now all servers show in sync.  Makes me think that this will not help with my problem of having machine GPO's fail to apply to machines, but we'll see!  Good luck!